# Route Audio from Computer to MIDI Piano?

Tags: audio, midi

I just got into DAWs and my computer's speakers suck. However, my privia 350m's speakers are much better. I was wondering if it were possible to route all the sound from my computer through a midi USB connection to where it is played on the keyboard's speakers.

Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MIDI interface transfers only information about notes; it is the receiving device that then generates sounds.

If your piano does not implement an additional audio interface on its USB port (and it does not look as if it does), then you have to connect the computer's line out to the piano's line in.

Answer (score 0):

here's how you do it. Open up your Privia. Find the speaker, follow it to the amp then cut the wires from the system to the amp. Now solder wires to the amp wires,solder those wires to a 1/4 inch audio jack, mount it in the case, reconnect the amp wires and the wires coming from the board/PCB. Congrats. You just modded your system.

Aside from that, no, you can't send audio through a midi cable. You really do need to learn how your tools work. Midi is a control protocol. Midi messages are 3 bytes. That's it. That's all. 24 on or off messages. If you did somehow turn midi into audio, it would sound very very lo fi and very harsh considering that it's 1s and 0s and therefore square waves. Even then, the device on the other end would need some kind of firmware modification or hardware modification that would require some awesome wizardry. I'm not sure it could even be done then, but for your purposes. No. It can not be done unless you plan on reverse engineering both devices, redesigning hardware, reverse engineering, reprogramming firmware, reflashing the system, and that's just the start.

Comment: Your second paragraph is fine, but your first one comes across as sarcastic. I'd suggest deleting it to just keep the good part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

nah ...the above answers are correct ....  Midi only transmits information like what note is played how long it is played for and what velocity it is played at
THen with this information you can send it to different types of instruments...THrough a midi cable there is no actual audio....Just instructions.